# Getting array values and adding them if they are numeric

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering how will I be able to get the values from the array generated by the code and then be able to add them in a single variable:

```
      var selector = 'input[name^="Textbook"]';
        $(selector).on('click', function() {
          var checked = $(selector + ':checked').map(function() {
            return {
              'type': this.type,
              'value': this.value
            };
          }).get().filter(function(o) {
            return '-1' !== o.value; // skip if value = -1(No)
          });
          console.log('checked inputs', checked);
        });
      }
```

I have checked functions in javascript such as .reduce which according to developer.mozila.org "reduces it to a single value". Though my goal is to add only the **numeric values** and the array has non-numeric values as well. How can i accomplish this? Thanks!

EDIT:
Here's an example of an array that the code above through the variable "checked" could output:

[image: Output of script above]

My goal is to add all the 'value' data and ignore the non-numeric ones.

EDIT2: Here's the HTML code. Not too sure how i could show you a working version as it relies on PHP as well and sites such as jsfiddle doesn't support it.

```
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input form="ES4S" type="radio" name="Supplies1" value="'.$Result[$i]['ID'].'"> Yes
                    <input form="ES4S" type="hidden" style="display:none" value="'.$Result[$i]['ID'].'" name="SuppliesID'.$i.'">
                  </label>
                  <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input form="ES4S" type="radio" name="Supplies1" value="-1">No
                  </label>
```

Comment: It looks like your function depends on the HTML - can you give an example of the HTML and the desired output?

Comment: Better to create a working snippet of your code along with desired output.

Comment: how's the html looks like? I am not sure when and how the user input.

Comment: Fill in the PHP bits with what would be rendered (e.g., copy the HTML of the rendered page, not your code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use reduce and check if the value is numeric when you're factoring it into the sum:

```js
var selector = 'input[name^="Textbook"]';

$(selector).parent().on('click', selector, function() {
  var checked = $(`${selector}:checked`).get()
  
  var sum = checked.reduce((c,p)=>{
    if (!(isNaN(+p.value)))
      c += +p.value;
    return c;
  },0)
  
  console.clear();
  console.log('sum',sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="radio-inline">
  <input form="ES4S" type="radio" name="Textbook" value="MPM Charge"> Yes
  <input form="ES4S" type="hidden" style="display:none" value="MPM Charge" name="Textbook">
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input form="ES4S" type="radio" name="Textbook" value="100">No
</label>

<br>

<label class="radio-inline">
  <input form="ES4S" type="radio" name="Textbook2" value="MPM Charge"> Yes
  <input form="ES4S" type="hidden" style="display:none" value="MPM Charge" name="Textbook2">
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
  <input form="ES4S" type="radio" name="Textbook2" value="300">No
</label>
```

There's no need to do filter first, since that would require iterating over your array twice.  Using reduce does everything in one pass.  The unary operator (`+`) is used to convert stringed numerics into a number to ensure `isNaN` tests positive.

Comment: Cheers! That worked well for me. This code made a lot more sense to me too! :)

Comment: A lot of improvements could be made, especially in variable names, but it comes down to preference. Good luck on your journey in finding out what works best for you

Comment: Hm i wonder if i can make this piecevof code run every second to check for checked input boxes instead of being triggered only when a form is clicked? @vol7ron

Comment: Check `setInterval`

Comment: I actually have.. but since its on 'click' it wont update every second regardless the interval value

Comment: You don’t need the click event any more, only what’s inside it. This is approaching the territory for another SO question, though

Comment: @DeathKing I recommend asking a new question

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter by is number then use reduce to get sum of the list

```js
var priceList = [{value:"190"}, {value:"180"}, {value:"Charge"}];

//shorthand code

console.log(priceList.map(n => Number(n.value)).filter(n => !isNaN(n)).reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }));

//full code

priceList =priceList.map(n => Number(n.value));
priceList = priceList.filter(n => !isNaN(n));
let priceSum = priceList.reduce(function(acc, val) { return acc + val; });
console.log(priceSum);
```

Comment: Hm the array above has 2 sets of variables (refer to the image i uploaded). Was wondering how to get what value. :)

Comment: I have updated my code to work with 2 sets of variables

Comment: @DeathKing can you please check and if any problem let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
const checked = [{"type":"radio","value":"100"},{"type":"checkbox","value":"MPM Charge"},{"type":"radio","value":"100.25"},{"type":"radio","value":"100"},{"type":"radio","value":"MPM Charge"},{"type":"radio","value":"100.5"},{"type":"radio","value":"100"},{"type":"radio","value":"MPM Charge"}]

Array.prototype.sum_values = function (prop, i, running_total = 0) {

  const array = Object.assign([], this)

  if (i === 0) {
    return running_total
  } else {
    const val = array[i - 1][prop] // property you want to add up
    const num = Number(val) // convert string to number
    if (isNaN(num)) { // if converted string in not a number
      return array.sum_values(prop, i - 1, running_total) // add nothing
    } else {
      return array.sum_values(prop, i - 1, running_total + num) // add number
    }

  }

}

const test = checked.sum_values('value', checked.length)
console.log(test) // 500.75
```

---

```
// Place the function where your checked array is console logged
var selector = 'input[name^="Textbook"]';
$(selector).on('click', function() {
  var checked = $(selector + ':checked').map(function() {
    return {
      'type': this.type,
      'value': this.value
    };
  }).get().filter(function(o) {
    return '-1' !== o.value; // skip if value = -1(No)
  });
  let sum = checked.sum_values('value', checked.length)
  console.log('checked inputs', sum);
  return sum
})
```